# How to generate reports in J2EE using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I need to generate reports based on the the criteria example generating a report of customers based on a particular month. But I do not know how to go about for report generation.
I am using JSP, Servlets and mysql in my project.

Any advice or help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain in details, what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to know if there are any jar files that we need to add?

Comment: If you're going to generate pdf/excel you can use iText

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jasper Reports` tool to generate reports as `XML/PDF/Excel Sheet`.

[Click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_getting_started.htm) for more idea about the Jasper Reports.

iReport GUI tool for designing jasper reports can be found [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-tutorials-help)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate report like below,

```
        String property = System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir");
        String jrxmlFileName = property + "/jasperreport/jrxml/test_jasper.jrxml";

        DataBeanMaker dataBeanMaker = new DataBeanMaker(2);
        List<DataBean> dataBeanList = dataBeanMaker.getDataBeanList();

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource =
            new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new File(jrxmlFileName));
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint =
            JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, property +
            "/ReportBeanDS.pdf");
```

Populating bean,

```
public class DataBeanMaker {
public List<DataBean> getDataBeanList() {
    List<DataBean> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<DataBean>();

    for(int i=0; i<this.devices; i++)
    {
        dataBeanList.add(addDevice("1", 2));
    }

    return dataBeanList;

}

private DataBean addDevice(String val1, Integer nodeChangeNumber, Integer val2) {

    DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
    dataBean.setValue1(val1);
    dataBean.setValue2(val2);

    return dataBean;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I I'm using eclipse and I found BIRT:

Get it here: http://www.eclipse.org/birt